# How to remap Ctrl to Caps Lock in a TTY?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, tty, capslock

I already understand how to remap keys in an X graphical server. However, I sometimes like to do work from a TTY and cannot seem to figure out a way to functionally remap `Ctrl` to `Caps Lock`.

I have already tried creating a `.keymap` file with the following contents:

```
keycode 37 = Control_L
```

Then sourcing it using `loadkeys`, but to no avail.

However, `37` is the keycode for `Ctrl` in X (according to `xmodmap -pke |  grep 'Control'`) so perhaps the keycode is different in a TTY? If so, how would I go about determining the correct key code and subsequently setting the remap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above by porkfreezer is great! To make this a permanent solution, you could make a `.settings` directory, or use your `.local` directory, to create your own keymap file like you were trying to do, that can be used when logging into a TTY.  To do this, I recommend copying the keyboard keymap you are currently useing (for me it's `us.map.gz`) to your home directory that you chose above, for me this looks like

```
cp /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz ~/.settings/
```

Then you can unzip and edit that file to contain the key mapping you want. For me I have switched the Escape key and Caps_Lock, for use with vim. Then create a symlink to this file to a directory where Linux can find it, like so:

```
sudo ln -s ~/.settings/custom.map /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/custom.map
```

Now, when in a TTY, you can run `sudo loadkeys custom` to load the key mapping.  To have this as the default, you could create a

```
/etc/vconsole.conf
```

file containing the line

```
KEYMAP=custom
```

Then edit your `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` file (you will need superuser privileges) by adding `keymap` to the end of the `hooks` list, this should look something like the following

```
...
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck keymap)
...
```

Then run

```
sudo mkinitcpio -p linux
```

And that's it! After a reboot, whenever you log into a TTY, your custom keymap will be used.

Hopfully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Kernel keycodes are different than X keycodes. Key 37 for the kernel is actually <kbd>K</kbd> (on qwerty). To find kernel keycodes you can use `showkey`:

```
$ showkey
kb mode was UNICODE
[ if you are using this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release    # I released enter
keycode  29 press      # I pressed control
keycode  29 release    # I released control
keycode  58 press      # I pressed caps lock
keycode  58 release    # I released caps lock
```

So, to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>:

```
keycode 29 = Caps_Lock
```

Or <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
keycode 58 = Control
```

Comment: I mapped `Ctrl` to the physical caps lock position by using `keycode 58 = Control` in my `.keymap` file but I had to use Bradon's solution otherwise whenever I pressed `Ctrl` it would lock the `Ctrl` function for all subsequent key presses and make the keyboard unusable.